# How can i count how many times the keywords user enter is the used in the essay. its doesn't check on the entire keyword

Tags: java

```
public static int keywordsChecker(String essay,String key) {
    int count = 1;

    String[] k=key.split(",");

    for (int i = 0; i < k.length-1; i++) {            

        if (essay.contains(k[i])) {    
            count++;
        }

    }

    return count;
}
```

Comment: yes it has a separator this is the essay .

Comment: why `k.length-1` ?

Comment: you need to be specific with example , what you have as input and what is your match string and expected output

Comment: why are you splitting the key variable?

Comment: can you be specific what your are expecting from the program

Comment: ^ this is the essay

Comment: Read: [ask] and then fix your question.

Comment: i'm not good at programming , so some of the code i found it by searching so that why i don't know what is used for .

Comment: “Stealing” code is great, but step 1 in that case is understanding how it works, or you are getting yourself into trouble, potentially a lot worse than this question reflects.

Comment: @Ole V.V. i got on trouble when i choose IT .

Comment: I smiled at your last comment, thx. If you’re serious, I hope it’s not too late to make a new choice.

Comment: anyway, i have another questions but this website not allowed more  than one . any one here could help me by another app ? i'll be grateful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To take into account that each keyword searched for may occur more than once, and to count such occurrences, you may use this inside your for loop:

```
        int indexOfOccurrence = essay.indexOf(k[i]);
        while (indexOfOccurrence > -1) {
            count++;
            indexOfOccurrence = essay.indexOf(k[i], indexOfOccurrence + 1);
        }
```

There are a couple of other issues in your code: I believe you need to initialize `count` to 0 (not 1). And to count also the last keyword in `key` your `for` loop should be `for (int i = 0; i < k.length; i++)` (without subtracting 1 from `k.length`). If you want, using `<=` would also work: `for (int i = 0; i <= k.length-1; i++)`, but this is non-standard, so I would not recommend it.